# How to use not equal to operator in if condition?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, operators

In other languages, we can use following code:

```
if(!False):
  print('not equal to operator worked.')
```

However, if I try to implement it in python, I am getting 'invalid syntax' error. Some people might say write True instead of False, but in my use case it's not possible. My use case is as following:

```
 def get_wrong_dtype_rows(col_name, data_type):
     arr = []
     for i,val in enumerate(df[col_name]):
        if !(type(val) is data_type):
            arr.append(i)
     return arr
```

I wanted to know, is their alternative way to solve this issue?

Comment: `if not False: ...`. In your case, however, use `if type(val) is not data_type`, or even better: `if not isinstance(val, data_type)`

Comment: Python has the `is not` construct.

Comment: Comparison operator in python !=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python,

`not` is equal to `!`

So, your code might be

```
 def get_wrong_dtype_rows(col_name, data_type):
     arr = []
     for i,val in enumerate(df[col_name]):
        if not type(val) is data_type:
            arr.append(i)
     return arr
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 'not'.
'not False' gives 'True' and so on.